# Как организовать опрос в чате с ботом используя чистый telegram bot api? Приходят результаты каждую минуту в вебхук

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь сделать опрос в приватном чате с ботом. Мне нужно получить ответ и остановить вопросник. Создается опросник удачно:

```
$options = '';
foreach($list as $key=>$row) {
  if ($options) {
    $options .= ',';
  }
  $options .= '"'.tgescape($row['val']).'"';
}
$options = "[$options]";
$params = [
    'chat_id'      => $chatId,
    'question'     => $item['actiontext'],
    'options'      => $options,
    'reply_markup' => getKeyboard($bot,$userId)
    
];
$URL = $TgAPI.'bot'.$bot['token'].'/sendPoll';
$ch = curl_init($URL);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT    => 60
));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
$Update = json_decode($output,true);
```

Но после ответа, каждую минуту в вебхук приходит вот это, а мне надо один раз получить и продолжить работу с ботом. Сообщение с опросом я удалил, не помогло.

{"update_id":199522756,
"poll":{"id":"5276163750276104317","question":"Question?","options":[{"text":"test1","voter_count":0},{"text":"test2","voter_count":1},{"text":"test3","voter_count":0}],"total_voter_count":1,"is_closed":false,"is_anonymous":true,"type":"regular","allows_multiple_answers":false}}

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, каким статус кодом отвечаете телеграмму? Это всего лишь предположение, но помнится, где-то в доке читал, что он ожидает увидеть 201.

Comment: 200, я со многими функциями работал, везде этот код работает

Comment: Вот тут есть инфа о том, как остановить опрос и получить финальные результаты (https://telegrambots.github.io/book/2/send-msg/native-polls-msg.html), однако, так же сказано, что bot не может отправлять опросы в приватные чаты.

Comment: @Borislav это то что нужно, я не задолго до вашего комментария нашел этот stopPoll. Если хотите - напишите ответ, я приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит попробовать явно остановить **опрос**, более подробно [тут](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/2/send-msg/native-polls-msg.html).

Однако, в документации сказано, что **bot** не может отправлять опросы в приватные чаты.

Comment: Может квизы не может, а regular может. В общем проверено, можно в приват боту.